# How to create a 2D Array Programmatically in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to create a 2d array like follows

```
var seriesArray = [{
    name: 'Year 1800',
    data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Year 1900',
    data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
}, {
    name: 'Year 2000',
    data: [814, 841, 3714, 727, 31]
}, {
    name: 'Year 2016',
    data: [1216, 1001, 4436, 738, 40]
}];
```

To view the example [Click Here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic)

What I'm doing to create such array

```
var continents = ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania']
var years = [1800, 1900, 2000, 2016];
for (var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
    var data = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < continents.length; j++) {
        data.push(10);
    }
    seriesArray.push([years[i], data]);
}
```

nothing gets displayed on the chart. Am I creating the array right? Is there any other way?

[Here the screenshot of seriesArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jANy7.png) data, I think my array is not associated array, can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Are you facing any problem? Your code looks fine.

Comment: Might I suggest that you reformat your question or open a new one specifying more information specifically about your chart issue as from as far as I can tell this looks fine atm.

Comment: "Nothing gets displayed on the chart" You haven't shown us any code that is related to rendering a chart...

Comment: nothing is displayed on the chart. I think i need to make associated array for this, but how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misordered your loops. And you have to build your row like this:

```
var continents = ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania']
var years = [1800, 1900, 2000, 2016];
for (var i = 0; i < continents.length; i++) {
    var data = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < years.length; j++) {
        data.push(10);
    }
    var row={};
    row['year']=years[i];
    row['data']=data;
    seriesArray.push(row);
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: bingo!, now chart is displayed :)